# Return a tuple of Map and String from UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to construct a temporary column from an expensive UDF that I need to run on each row of my `Dataset[Row]`. Currently it looks something like:

```
val myUDF = udf((values: Array[Byte], schema: String) => {
    val list = new MyDecoder(schema).decode(values)

    val myMap = list.map(
        (value: SomeStruct) => (value.field1, value.field2)
    ).toMap

    val field3 = list.head.field3
    return (myMap, field3)
})

val decoded = myDF.withColumn("decoded_tmp", myUDF(col("data"), lit(schema))
                  .withColumn("myMap", col("decoded_tmp._1"))
                  .withColumn("field3", col("decoded_tmp._2"))
                  .drop("decoded_tmp")
```

However, when I try to compile this, I get a type mismatch error:

> type mismatch;
>    found   : (scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double], String)
>    required: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]

How can I get around this, or will I have to have 2 expensive UDF functions, one to produce `myMap` and the other to produce the `field3` column?

Comment: can you post the code of MyDecoder?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan The `decode` function simply accepts an `Array[Byte]` and returns a `List[SomeStruct]`, where `SomeStruct` is just a case class with 3 fields, `field1: String`, `field2: Double` and `field3: String`.

Comment: it would be helpful if you update the question with the code. And update with how you myDF looks like . some sample rows would suffice.